# minikube - Create a file from Job on local machine

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I want to create a file from a job on my local machine, where I use minikube. I want to do that in `/tmp` directory.

Here's my CronJob definition

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  generateName: test-
spec:
  schedule: 1 2 * * *
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
            - name: test-volume
              hostPath:
                path: /tmp
          containers:
            - name: test-job
              image: busybox
              args:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - touch /data/ok.txt
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /data
                  name: test-volume
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I mounted `/tmp` from my machine to `/data` on minikube. I did that using `minikube mount "/tmp:data"`, and then I checked via `minikube ssh` if it works fine.

The problem is that with this configuration I cannot see the file `ok.txt` being created in `/tmp`, I can't even see it in `/data` on my minikube. I added a sleep command before to check if it works and get into the container to check if the file has been created. I listed all files from `/data` from the Pod, and the file was there.

How can I create this `ok.txt` file on my machine, in the `/tmp`?

Thanks in advance for help!!

Comment: Are you using any virtualization software like WMVare or VirtualBox? Could you share your `PV` and `PVC` YAMLs?

Comment: @PjoterS I'm using minikube with docker driver. I don't any PVs and PVCs. I only want to create a file from this Job on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

#### Root cause

Root cause of this issue is related to `paths` in `YAML`.

In [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) documentation regarding [mount](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/mount/) command, you can find information:

`minikube mount [flags] <source directory>:<target directory>`

where:

- `source directory` is directory path on your machine
- `target directory` is directory path mounted in minikube

To achieve what you want, you can to use `minikube mount "/tmp:/data" .

**Side Note**

Minikube driver was set to `Docker`.

Please keep in mind that `mount` must be stay alive for whole time.

```
  Mounting host path /tmp into VM as /data ...
...
  Userspace file server: ufs starting
✅  Successfully mounted /tmp to /data

  NOTE: This process must stay alive for the mount to be accessible ...
```

#### Solution

**Minikube Mount:**

`$ minikube mount "/tmp:/data"`

**CronJob YAML:**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *" # I have changed schedule time for testing
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:   
          containers:
            - name: test-job
              image: busybox
              args:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - touch /data/ok.txt
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /data
                  name: test-volume
          volumes:
            - name: test-volume
              hostPath:
                path: /data
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

#### Output

**On Host:**

```
$ pwd
/home/user
user@minikube:~$ cd /tmp
user@minikube:/tmp$ ls | grep ok.txt
ok.txt
```

**On Minikube**

```
user@minikube:~$ minikube ssh
docker@minikube:~$ pwd
/home/docker
docker@minikube:~$ ls
docker@minikube:~$ cd /data
docker@minikube:/data$ ls | grep ok 
ok.txt
```

Please let me know if it worked for you.